# INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE error for no understandable reason

Tags: android

I am developing my Android app and I want to use my own database file. My DB is about 115 MB so I have to split it to 1 MB parts to transfer it from assets into phone during installation. As you can understand my app is going to be huge so I decide to compress it, to transfer it into phone and then decompress it to the SD card and use it. When I compress the DB, the size is reduced from 115 MB to 41 MB and, because of asset max size, I split it also in 1 MB parts.

When I try to install my app in my testing device (not a VM), I face the following absurd:
when I put in assets file in android project all the uncompressed database parts (115 parts/ 115 MB size) I am taking `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE` and this is normal. After that, I delete all that files from assets and copy only 50 parts of my uncompressed database, which size are 50 MB and the app run fine! After that, I delete again all that files from assets and copy the compressed database parts (41 parts/ 41 MB size) and I take the same error `Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`. How is that possible? Is there any reason for that, any explanation because of the compressed files? I want to mention that while I try it, I am not doing any task when the app start. I only put the files in asset folder and start the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An app can only take 50 mb, if you want to use more space you need to use [expansion files](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html).